# Multibranch Pipeline Jenkinsfile Looking for advice/Feedback

Tags: dsl, pipeline, cloudbees, jenkins-workflow

Ok, Below you find my opus.. (lol not really)  but still this is my attempt to take a mess and automate it.  Those who are willing, any advice would be appreciated.

The project all lives in one git repo. very much like https://github.com/jmvanryn/multibranchPipeline

some of my questions are..

1. could I be doing some of this better? how do I use Global variables?
2. you can see I'm defining some things twice. why does GIT pull twice?
3. is there a way to get the cobertura report plugin to work?
4. env.BRANCH_NAME gives me "feature/FeatureName"  is there a
   DSL/Groovy way to trim it to just FeatureName?

   ```
   node {
    wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
       def user = env.BUILD_USER_ID
   }

   env.JAVA_HOME = tool 'JDK1.7.0.21'
   def mvnHome = tool 'M3'
   def nodeJS = tool 'NodeJSv5.6.0'
   env.MAVEN_OPTS = "-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
   env.PATH = "${mvnHome}/bin:${nodeJS}/bin:${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"

   //checkout scm
   sh 'git rev-parse --verify HEAD > hash.txt'
   env.GIT_COMMIT = readFile('hash.txt')
   env.GIT_COMMIT = env.GIT_COMMIT.trim()

   setVersion();

   stage("Build Core")
   hipchatSend color: 'GREEN', notify: true, room: '1654572'
   BuildIt ("sharedLib1")
   BuildIt ("sharedLib2")

   stage("Build Modules")
   parallel "first-ui": {
       BuildIt ("first-ui")
   }, "second-ui": {
       BuildIt ("second-ui")
   }, "first-ws": {
       BuildIt ("first-ws")
   }, "second-ws": {
       BuildIt ("second-ws")
   }

   stage("Archive files")
   echo("================================== Archive Stage ==================================")
   step([$class: 'ArtifactArchiver', artifacts: '**/target/*.war', fingerprint: true])
   //step([$class: 'ArtifactArchiver', artifacts: 'CONFIG/*.*', fingerprint: true])
   step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'])

   step([$class: 'hipchat', room: '1654572', startNotification: false, notifySuccess: true, notifyAborted: false, notifyNotBuil: false, notifyUnstable: false, notifyFailure: true, notifyBackToNormal: false])

   stage("Notification")
   step([$class: 'Mailer', notifyEveryUnstableBuild: true, recipients: 'jvanryn@liaison-intl.com', sendToIndividuals: true])
   }

   def BuildIt(module) {

   sh "echo '================================== Build Stage : ${module} ==================================';\
   cd ${module};\
   mvn --batch-mode -V -U -e clean deploy -U -DskipITs sonar:sonar -Dsonar.branch=${env.BRANCH_NAME} -Dsurefire.useFile=false"
   }

   def setVersion () {

   def JobCode = env.BRANCH_NAME
   def JobName = env.JOB_NAME
   def BuildURL = env.BUILD_URLD
   def BuildNum = env.BUILD_NUMBER
   def RevNum = env.GIT_COMMIT
   def WrkSpce = pwd()

       echo "Running Build for: "+JobCode
       // update version to a unique version
       def script=WrkSpce+"/Tools/PomVersionUpdater.sh "+JobCode+"-"+RevNum+"-"+BuildNum

       sh script
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can create a .mvn folder with jvm.config and maven.config to store all those xmx parameters and others, so everyone is using the same build settings.

You also need a try/catch block to send some notification if the build fails.

Other than that it looks ok, could be better but it works